# Torsion-free submodule of maximal rank

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a free $\mathbb{Q}[t_1^{\pm 1},\dots,t_\mu^{\pm 1}]$-module of rank $n$.

If $M$ is a submodule of $A$, I know that it must be torsion-free. Assuming the rank of $M$ is $n$ can I conclude that $M$ is actually free?

Comment: Where the rank of $M$ means...?

Comment: The dimension of $M \otimes Q$, where $Q$ is the field of fractions.

Comment: In general, a non-zero ideal of an integral domain has rank one and it is not necessarily free unless it is principal. But your ring is not a PID unless $\mu=1$.

Comment: yes, whence my question!

Comment: I don't get it. I just told you that the answer to your question is **NO** unless $\mu=1$, and for $\mu=1$ your ring is a PID, so all submodules of free modules are free.

Comment: Edit: okay my mistake, thank you!